# Acesso ao http-headers da API do Wordpress usando Angular 2

Tags: api, angular, http-headers

Estou com uma dúvida bem simples no **Angular 2**.

Eu tenho uma aplicação que se conecta com a **API Rest do Wordpress** e estou com um problema que imagino ser bem simples, mas não estou conseguindo achar na web uma solução.

Eu preciso recuperar os dados que vem no **http-headers** na API que estou acessando, dados que vem como total de postagens e quantidade de páginas, eu sei quais são os parâmetros, mas não consigo acessar eles.

Como faço para acessar informações no Header?

Segue abaixo o código do método que faço a requisição:

```
getNoticias(page: number) {
    return this._http.get(this._apiUrl + "noticias/?page=" + page, { headers: this.getHeaders()})
           .map(res => res.json())
           .catch(this.throwError);
}
```

Comment: AngularJS é uma coisa, Angular 2 é outra. JSON não tem *header*, provavelmente o que você precisa é acessar o *header* de uma **requisição HTTP** que tem como *payload* um JSON. Seria bom você [edit] a pergunta e adicionar o código que usa para fazer a chamada para a API.

Comment: De fato, nas tags marquei http-headers, mas na dúvida marquei de forma equivocada.